# How to remove manually installed libraries?

Tags: software-installation, software-uninstall

I've installed some libraries (`libsfml`) manually with `cmake`. But now I need an older version. So I installed it, but it seems that when I compile a program for `sfml` it is using the newest version.

What can I do to **completely remove** the newest library and use the old version?

- I tried to `make uninstall` but there is no uninstall option in the Makefile.
- I tried the `checkinstall` command to create the package unsusccessfully:

> Copying files to the temporary directory...OK
>
> Stripping ELF binaries and libraries...OK
>
> Compressing man pages...OK
>
> Building file list...OK
>
> Building Debian package... FAILED!
>
> *** Failed to build the package

The log files shows:

> dpkg-deb: error: parsing file
>   '/var/tmp/tmp.JtOp7x1Mrp/package/DEBIAN/control' near line 7 package
>   'sfml':  error in Version string 'build-1': version number does not
>   start with digit /var/tmp/tmp.JtOp7x1Mrp/dpkgbuild.log (END)

I've seen there is an `install_manifest.txt` with all the paths affected:

> /usr/local/./include/SFML/System/Err.hpp
>   /usr/local/./include/SFML/System/Thread.inl
>   /usr/local/./include/SFML/System/Clock.hpp
>   /usr/local/./include/SFML/System/Utf.inl
>   /usr/local/./include/SFML/System/Time.hpp
>   /usr/local/./include/SFML/System/Lock.hpp
>    ...

Is it ok if I manually remove all those entries and then reinstall the version I want?

Answer (score 5):

## If you installed the latest library by compiling manually:

Go to the build directory and run:

> sudo make uninstall

If that does not work, run:

> sudo checkinstall

Then a debian package will be generated. Open it (from Software Center) and press Remove.

## If you installed the latest library though APT/Software Center:

Run this to remove it:

> sudo apt-get remove libsfml

Comment: Please, check my updates

Comment: Sorry I have no further knowledge. You should put this question in StackOverFlow, or offer a bounty.

Comment: ok thank you, +1 for the options you gave me, good to know despite it didn't work in my case.